# PDE and finding the integral representation to the solution of the pde

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Assume $u(t,x)=v(\frac{x^2}{t})$ for $t>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> i)Prove that $u$ solves  the equation
>
> $\partial_t u-\partial_x^2u=0$ in $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$
>
> if and only if for $z\geq 0$
>
> $4zv''(z)+(2+z)v'(z)=0$.
>
> ii)Show that the general soltion of the above equation is
>
> $v(z)=c_1\int_0^ze^{-s/4}s^{-1/2}ds+c_2$.

Here's how I went about it:

$\partial_tu=\partial_tv=-x^2/t^2\partial_tv$

$\partial_xu=\partial_xv=2x/t\partial_xv$

$\partial_{xx}u=\partial_{xx}v=2/t\partial_xv+4x^2/t^2\partial_{xx}v$

Plugging it all in into the first equation I get:

$-x^2/t^2\partial_tv-2/t\partial_xv+4x^2/t^2\partial_{xx}v=0$

For $z=x^2/t$ I get:

$-z/t\partial_tv(z)-2/t\partial_xv(z)+4z/t\partial_{xx}v(z)=0$

$\rightarrow$ $z\partial_tv(z)+2\partial_xv(z)+4z\partial_{xx}v(z)=0$

I don't know if I'm allowed to factor out into $(2+z)v'(z)$ since one is a derivative in regard to $t$ and the other one in regard to $x$.

And as far as ii) is concerned, I'm not sure how to solve this. I was thinking of applying Fourier Transform on the second equation but that seems to make it more complicated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You writing $\partial_t v$ and $\partial_x v$ indicates a possible misunderstanding of functions and/or derivatives and/or the chain rule, so it is hard to give a good answer.

Try to think of $v$ as a function of one variable $z$. Thus you are only allowed to write $\partial_z v$, and since there is only one variable, we don't use the $\partial$ symbol, but $\frac{d v}{d z}$ or just $v'$. 
For clarity, let's write $\frac{dv}{dz}$.

Now, the assumption is that $u(t, x) = v(x^2 / t)$. Maybe it is a good idea to write $g(t, x) = x^2 / t$, so that $u(t, x) = v(g(t, x))$. The chain rule gives
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}
=
\frac{d v}{d z} \; \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}
%
\quad\text{and}\quad
%
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
=
\frac{d v}{d z} \; \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
.
$$

More precisely, 
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t, x)
=
\frac{d v}{d z}(g(t, x)) \; \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t, x)
$. 
Here is where you might get confused: there is no $z$ to derive for? This is because $\frac{d v}{d z}$ is a function, and if I wrote $v'$ instead -- it's the same thing -- maybe you wouldn't have noticed it.

When you do the second derivative, you need to apply the product rule and then the chain rule, as you in fact did.

This doesn't answer the question, but with luck it will set some things straight.